# How can I integrate OpenID in my project?

Tags: grails, spring-security, openid, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I want to implement login mechanism through openID strategy in Grails.

So how can I do it?

Here I have used google mail paid services.(means paid account).

How can I get openId for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options in the form of plugins. Which plugin of course, depends upon your requirements. Here is a partial list of the most popular OpenID related Grails plugins.

- [Grails OpenID](http://grails.org/plugin/openid)
- [OpenID for Spring Security](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-openid)
- [OpenID for Shiro](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro-openid)

Here is [a blog post](http://softwareengineering101.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/integrating-grails-2-with-spring-security-openidgoogle-single-sign-on/) that gives you an example of using Spring Security in a Grails application with a Google account.

Comment: yeah, I am looking for that, sighIn with google account.

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to a blog post explaining how you can do that with one of the mentioned plugins.